# How to sync components sharing state hook in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I'm trying to make 2 components in sync with their parent component state using React hooks.
I'm using *horizontal* and *vertical stepper* as 2 separate components from material UI, and their parent class has the content of the stepper and the state in which they both **should** share.
The reason I'm using the *horizontal* and *vertical stepper* is to make the UI responsive as possible.

The problem I'm encountering is that when the `activeStep` is incremented by one of the components i.e. horizontal stepper, upon my understanding of the component mount life cycle. the render method is called and the Activestep is incremented and reflected in the dom. but it is only reflected in the horizontal stepper. the change only propagates in the horizontal stepper component. when navigating the *vertical stepper* component, it returns the initial state of the hook which was originally set to 0.

I'm trying to make *Horizontal* and *Vertical stepper* in sync with the `activeStep` in the *stepperContent*, and any change in the state should propagate in both components.

**My Question is**

How do I make them in sync with the `activeState` in *stepperContent* stateful functional component?

**steppertContent.JSX**

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const useVerticalStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  actionsContainer: {
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  resetContainer: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
  },
}));

export const useHorizontalStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
  },
  backButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  instructions: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(1),
  },
}));

export const StepperContent = () => {
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(activeStep);
  }, [activeStep]);
  // console.log(activeStep);

  const handleNext = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setActiveStep(0);
  };
  return { activeStep, handleNext, handleBack, handleReset };
};

export const getSteps = () => {
  return [
    "ACCOUNT SETUP",
    "PERSONAL INFORMATION",
    "CONTACT INFORMATION",
    "FAMILY INFORMATION",
    "SCHOOL INFORMATION",
    "ADMISSION INFORMATION",
    "SUBMIT INFORMATION",
  ];
};

export const getStepContent = (stepIndex) => {
  switch (stepIndex) {
    case 0:
      return "CREATE YOUR ACCOUNT";
    case 1:
      return "What is an ad group anyways?";
    case 2:
      return "This is the bit I really care about!";
    default:
      return "Unknown stepIndex";
  }
};
```

**horizontalFormStepper.JSX**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Stepper,
  Step,
  StepLabel,
  Button,
  Typography,
} from "@material-ui/core/";
import {
  getStepContent,
  getSteps,
  useHorizontalStyles,
  StepperContent,
} from "./common/stepperContent";

const HorizontalFormStepper = () => {
  const classes = useHorizontalStyles();
  const { activeStep, handleReset, handleBack, handleNext } = StepperContent();
  const steps = getSteps();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} alternativeLabel>
        {steps.map((label) => (
          <Step key={label}>
            <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
          </Step>
        ))}
      </Stepper>
      <div>
        {activeStep === steps.length ? (
          <div>
            <Typography className={classes.instructions}>
              All steps completed
            </Typography>
            <Button onClick={handleReset}>Reset</Button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <Typography className={classes.instructions}>
              {getStepContent(activeStep)}
            </Typography>
            <div>
              <Button
                disabled={activeStep === 0}
                onClick={handleBack}
                className={classes.backButton}
              >
                Back
              </Button>
              <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleNext}>
                {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? "Finish" : "Next"}
                {/* {console.log(steps.length - 1)} */}
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HorizontalFormStepper;
```

**verticalFormStepper.JSX**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Stepper,
  Step,
  StepLabel,
  StepContent,
  Button,
  Paper,
  Typography,
  Grid,
  Container,
} from "@material-ui/core/";
import {
  getStepContent,
  getSteps,
  useVerticalStyles,
  StepperContent,
} from "./common/stepperContent";

const VerticalFormStepper = () => {
  const classes = useVerticalStyles();
  const steps = getSteps();
  const { activeStep, handleBack, handleNext, handleReset } = StepperContent();
  return (
    <Container fixed maxWidth="sm">
      <Grid>
        <Paper variant="outlined" elevation={2}>
          <div className={classes.root}>
            <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} orientation="vertical">
              {steps.map((label, index) => (
                <Step key={label}>
                  <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
                  <StepContent>
                    <Typography>{getStepContent(index)}</Typography>
                    <div className={classes.actionsContainer}>
                      <div>
                        <Button
                          disabled={activeStep === 0}
                          onClick={handleBack}
                          className={classes.button}
                        >
                          Back
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                          variant="contained"
                          color="primary"
                          onClick={handleNext}
                          className={classes.button}
                        >
                          {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? "Finish" : "Next"}
                        </Button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </StepContent>
                </Step>
              ))}
            </Stepper>
            {activeStep === steps.length && (
              <Paper square elevation={0} className={classes.resetContainer}>
                <Typography>
                  All steps completed - you&apos;re finished
                </Typography>
                <Button onClick={handleReset} className={classes.button}>
                  Reset
                </Button>
              </Paper>
            )}
          </div>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default VerticalFormStepper;
```

Comment: It looks like you can put this on codesandbox, can you do that?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/young-feather-70x21?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks! So the issue we want to fix here, is that we don't want to lose the user's progress when switching to `horizontal` and `vertical` stepper - or vice versa.

Comment: The problem is that you're calling `StepperContent` in both components, instead of that, call it only once in the parent component and pass the result value as props to the component, here is a working version https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-dream-5x4ko

Comment: In other words, by calling `StepperContent` in each component you're creating two states, each component has its own state instead of them sharing the same state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution, is to use [`Context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) API.

```js
// StepperContent.jsx
...

export const StepperContentContext = createContext();
export const useStepperContent = () => useContext(StepperContentContext);

export const StepperContentProvider = ({ children }) => {
  ...

  const value = { activeStep, handleNext, handleBack, handleReset };

  return (
    <StepperContentContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </StepperContentContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

So instead of using `StepperContent`, you can now use `useStepperContent` hook.

```js
// HorizontalFormStepper.jsx
...
import {
  getStepContent,
  getSteps,
  useHorizontalStyles,
  useStepperContent
} from "./common/StepperContent";

const HorizontalFormStepper = () => {
  const classes = useHorizontalStyles();
  const {
    activeStep,
    handleReset,
    handleBack,
    handleNext
  } = useStepperContent();
  ...
```

[image: Edit sleepy-bell-2pgq2]

*Might be overkill, but it's there.*